# How to git push to two repositories while git pull from one repository

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab

I'm working on linux server (non-desktop) and I have two repositories. One is for development (github), the other is a local repository of my lab (gitlab).

What I need is to keep the two repositories always exactly the same, and I can push and pull on my dev repository, whereas only push on my local repository so that my colleagues can `git pull` from my lab repository. My lab-repository is used only for sharing my project with my colleagues: I do nothing but `git push` and they do nothing but `git pull`. That's all.

Well, you may ask why don't use the dev repository. That's because they have no right to connect to the Internet.

I don't like to execute many commands for each action. For example, for now I have to execute the commands below to `git push` to the two repositories:

```
cd devRepo
# coding here
# git add & git commit & git push here
cd ../myLabRepo
cp -r ../devRepo/* ./
# git add & git commit & git push here
```

This is kind of boring. Ofc, I know I can use bash script but I'm wondering if there are some specialized tool to do so or maybe Git has the capacity to do so.

Comment: What is the exact need? Do you want not to have the ability to pull on your local repository? If not, then what is your exact need?

Comment: Do both repositories have set remote?

Comment: @Levin  Yes. They do.

Comment: @LajosArpad   I re-edited the post.

Comment: Asking for tools or other off-site resources is off topic here, so I will focus on a bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify more than one **push** location for the same remote.

```
git remote set-url --add --push <remote name> <push url>
```

Check this with `git remote -v`

You should see the original push and fetch URLs, along with the extra push URL you just added.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the whole stuff that you have into a bash script and run that. Otherwise, you can add a remote to your first repository and do a push there as well, instead of copying your whole project.

```
git add & git commit & git pull origin master & git push origin master & git push local master
```